Release notes for Android Google Play Billing Library 7.1.0 (com.android.billingclient:billing)
Currently the public page for release notes for the Google Play Billing Library only lists version 7.0.0 as latest version. But for almost a week version 7.1.0 is available. So I'm wondering if anybody has more concrete details on the changes in 7.1.0.

They unfortunatly always take a while to update the docs. Better to not upgrade until it's available.

Interesting they'd update the library before the documentation. Horse before the cart etc.

Yeah, I had some issues with 7.0.0 or rather some of my users, so I would hope 7.1.0 contains some fixes in that regard. So at this point I'm down to just crossing my fingers and praying to Google Almighty.

Up to 7.1.1 now with still no release notes since 7.0.0.

Finally the updated the release notes, even for 7.1.1!!!!!1! https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/release-notes
